# r How to check if values exist in a previous period (rolling)

Tags: r

Here is my dataset:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(14609, 14609, 14609, 14609, 14699, 14699, 14699, 14699, 14790, 14790, 14790, 14790), class = "Date"), 
ID = structure(c(5L, 4L, 6L, 10L, 9L, 3L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 1L, 
10L, 2L), .Label = c("B00NYQ2", "B03J9L7", "B05DZD1", "B06HC42", 
"B09V3X7", "B09YCC8", "X6114659", "X6478816", "X6556701", 
"X6812555"), class = "factor"), Name = structure(c(10L, 4L, 
9L, 8L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 1L), .Label = c("AIRA", 
"BOUS", "CSCS", "EVF", "GTB", "JER", "MGB", "MPR", "NVB", 
"TTNP"), class = "factor"), Score = c(55.075, 54.5, 53.325, 
52.175, 70.275, 69.825, 60.15, 60.025, 56.175, 52.65, 52.175, 
52.125), Score.rank = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L)), .Names = c("Date", "ID", "Name", "Score", "Score.rank"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm trying to find which IDs come in and out when we go into a new period.

What i mean by that is..i want to compare if the ID was present in the previous period, denoted by "Date".

If it existed in the previous period (date), It should not return anything.

If it did not exist in the previous period, it should return "IN".

I also want to show that if does not exist in the *next* period, it should return an "OUT".
ie the this period's OUTs should be equal to next periods INs

my expected dataframe is supposed to look like this

```
Date        ID         Name     Score   Score.rank  THIS PERIOD NEXT PERIOD
31/12/2009  B09V3X7    TTNP     55.075  1                        OUT
31/12/2009  B06HC42    EVF      54.5    2                        OUT
31/12/2009  B09YCC8    NVB      53.325  3                        OUT
31/12/2009  X6812555    MPR     52.175  4       
31/3/2010   X6556701    MGB     70.275  1              IN   
31/3/2010   B05DZD1     CSCS    69.825  2              IN        OUT
31/3/2010   X6812555    MPR     60.15   3       
31/3/2010   X6478816    JER     60.025  4              IN        OUT
30/6/2010   X6114659    BOUS    56.175  1              IN   
30/6/2010   B00NYQ2     GTB     52.65   2              IN   
30/6/2010   X6812555    MPR     52.175  3       
30/6/2010   B03J9L7     AIRA    52.125  4              IN
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction as to how to do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks @SymbolixAU. ok let me try reposting the data

Comment: oh oops. ok i expanded the dataset if that helps?

Comment: Can you update with your expected output for the given dataframe?

Comment: thanks @RonakShah added the expected dataframe output. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description and example doesn't match, unfortunately.
Considering your description, it seems you want to tag entry and exit conditions for the IDs.

Which can be achieved as:

```
dft %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  dplyr::mutate( This_period = if_else(Date == min(Date), "IN", NULL) ) %>%
  dplyr::mutate( Next_period = if_else(Date == max(Date), "OUT", NULL))
```

and returns:

```
#Source: local data frame [12 x 7]
#Groups: ID [10]
#
#         Date       ID   Name  Score Score.rank This_period Next_period
#       <date>   <fctr> <fctr>  <dbl>      <int>       <chr>       <chr>
#1  2009-12-31  B09V3X7   TTNP 55.075          1          IN         OUT
#2  2009-12-31  B06HC42    EVF 54.500          2          IN         OUT
#3  2009-12-31  B09YCC8    NVB 53.325          3          IN         OUT
#4  2009-12-31 X6812555    MPR 52.175          4          IN        <NA>
#5  2010-03-31 X6556701    MGB 70.275          1          IN         OUT
#6  2010-03-31  B05DZD1   CSCS 69.825          2          IN         OUT
#7  2010-03-31 X6812555    MPR 60.150          3        <NA>        <NA>
#8  2010-03-31 X6478816    JER 60.025          4          IN         OUT
#9  2010-06-30 X6114659   BOUS 56.175          1          IN         OUT
#10 2010-06-30  B00NYQ2    GTB 52.650          2          IN         OUT
#11 2010-06-30 X6812555    MPR 52.175          3        <NA>         OUT
#12 2010-06-30  B03J9L7   AIRA 52.125          4          IN         OUT
```

However, your example suggests you want to exclude the `min(Date)` from `this_period` check and the `max(Date)` from the `Next_period` check. Is it so? if yes, is `score.rank` somehow related to `Date`?
please clarify.

Comment: Thanks so much @Aramis7d! To answer your question, thinking about it, i think that it doesnt have to exclude min(Date) and max(Date). However I'm getting 2 errors, first i got "Error: could not find function "if_else" ". then after removing the underscore to just "ifelse", i get another error:- Error: replacement has length zero
In addition: Warning message: In rep(no, length.out = length(ans)) :
  'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL. Any thoughts on why i'm getting this? thanks again

Comment: Can someone please explain the use of "min" in [  Date == min(Date)   ] and "max " in [  Date == max(Date)   ]? thanks in advance

Comment: `??if_else` into the console would tell you it's the function from `dplyr` while `ifelse` is from `base` R.  They work differently.
`max` and `min` returns the corresponding maximum or minimum value of the argument `Date` within the group, which we compare the current value with. This makes sure we check for the first or last occurrence of the ID and tag it accordingly.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply @Aramis7d. Finally figured out what was wrong. My dplyr package was not updated to include "if_else". Once i updated, it worked perfectly. Thanks again!